# no puedo certificar SSL en mi sitio WEB con certifyMyWeb

Tags: aws, iis, ssl, certificado-ssl, windows-server

Mi sitio está alojado en windows server 2019 aws, uso iis, funciona OK, pero cuando quiero realizar la certificación SSL con "certificar la web" me dice un error como:

```
Validation of the required challenges did not complete successfully. Validation failed: www.my.site.com [dns] 
Response from Certificate Authority: 2a02:4780:3:713:0:2d3a:bd70:2: Invalid response from http://www.my.site.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/EC4jvnUB3NjZ2i8tSXi50ylXg3ELmnixFePnlVkS_kE: 404 [Forbidden :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized]
```

¿qué puedo hacer?

He abierto el puerto 80 y concedido permisos de lectura a la carpeta, ejecuto la prueba en `certifyMyWeb`:

```
Al Tests Completed OK
Grupo de aplicaciones: Configuration Override Enabled
© Http Challenge Server proceso disponible
© URL verificada es accesible: http://
nt mm- | -known/acme-challenge/configcheck
URL verificada accesible: http://
comacme-challenge/configcheck
```

Sigo sin poder obtener el certificado correspondiente.

Comment: Las conexiones seguras no van por el puerto 80 sino por el 443. HTTP usa el puerto 80 y HTTPS el 443

Comment: si, pero necesito el 80 para hacer el test

Comment: Pero con el 80 no vas a tener SSL. Si no hay SSL no vas a tener certificado